# View monero subaddress balance without monero-wallet-cli

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

Is there any way to

1. get the balance of a subaddress, with only the view key (programmaticly) and no monero-wallet-cli installed? At best a js lib. Assume it is connected to an open node.
2. run the monero-wallet-cli on an aws lambda?

I know of the monero-javascript project.
https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-javascript

Sadly I can't run a wallet-rpc node on my own.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot get a *balance* with a view key alone. All you can do with a view key is view incoming transactions - not get a wallet balance. To determine a wallet *balance* you also need a way to know what is *spent*. With a view-only *wallet*, you can import key images which will enable you to view a balance. Thus, you would first have to create a view-only wallet using the view key and then import key images.
2. For programatic access you would use the `monero-wallet-rpc`, *not* `monero-wallet-cli`. In theory you could run this on AWS Lambda but whichever tool/host you used, you still need access to a daemon also.

Comment: After further investigation, I need `monero-wallet-rpc` running on an aws lambda. Sadly the host is a problem here, for it only can execute javascript, no binaries. Do you have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: "it only can execute javascript, no binaries" <- Is not true. You can easily package binaries for deployment to AWS Lambda and then launch the binary in whatever language you are using.